# What to do when everything about a question and answer is wrong for the application

Tags: discussion

This [INSERT INTO with VALUES and SELECT STATEMENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602710/insert-into-with-values-and-select-statement) is inaccurate in both question and answer.

A date is quoted, in MS Access dates should have hash  - it is possible it is a string, but then the table design is wrong.

A numeric value is quoted - it is possible it is a string, but then the table design is wrong.

The answerer states that strings should have single quotes in MS Access, this is not true, it is a lot more complicated than that.

Do I down vote both question and answer? Do something else? I would not like a person to find this question and be guided by it.

Comment: I personally would downvote and/or comment and then if you want post a correct answer that solves all of the problems.